# F12 Go To Definition not working for CSS in CSHTML files - VS2017

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on my first Asp.net Core 2.0 Mvc web site.
Normally I use web forms, but I'm trying something new.

In my .cshtml files I cannot F12 or right click and "go to definition" on CSS classes. I thought something may be wrong with my install but I was able to open up a web forms application and it works just fine from an ASPX page.

I have seen topics from 2013 about this issue, but no solutions.

I have installed web essentials, but that didn't work either.
This is something I use regularly and it is hard to do it manually especially when you are looking at a minified CSS file.
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Pro.

Comment: I know of no way to do that in .cshtml files.  If someone chimes in with a way to accomplish that I'd love such a feature too.

Answer (score -2):

The ReSharper extension for Visual Studio adds this feature.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReSharper_by_Language__CSS__Navigation.html#navigation-within-css-file